# Inconsistency with R's Global Environment in a function call

Tags: r

I was playing around with R and noticed some inconsistencies with the Global Environment surrounding function calls differing from the actual global environment.

Consider the following:

```
> test = function () 
+ {
+     print(environmentName(as.environment(-1)))
+     print(ls(as.environment(-1)))
+     print(environmentName(.GlobalEnv))
+     print(ls(.GlobalEnv))
+     as.environment(-1)
+ }
> foo = 1
> ls()
[1] "foo"  "test"
> test()
[1] ""
[1] "doTryCatch" "expr"       "handler"    "name"       "parentenv" 
[1] "R_GlobalEnv"
[1] "foo"  "test"
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Within the function call, `as.environment(-1)` returns an environment that claims it is `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>` but when calling `environmentName` on said environment, its name is an empty character. Furthermore, the contents of it differ from what is in the true global environment. What exactly is going on here?

I first noticed the error using `mget` within a call, as a variable defined globally could not be found. This seems counter-intuitive because normally when referencing a variable within a function, R will search upwards in the enclosing environments until it finds a definition for a variable, including the global environment.

Comment: It seems that `environmentName` is not needed to show this difference.   The two print statements here give different results: 
`test <- function() { e <- as.environment(-1); print(e); print(as.environment(-1)) }; test()`

Comment: Also compare: `print(as.environment(-1)); I(as.environment(-1)); c(as.environment(-1))`. They all give different results, presumably related to how and where they evaluate their supplied arguments, though it's not really clear to me what's going on. Relevant C-level source code is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/envir.c#L2833) and [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/envir.c#L2789). (The latter bit clued me in to the equivalence of `as.environment(-1)` and `pos.to.env(-1)`.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a consequence of lazy evaluation:

```
test <- function () {
  e <- as.environment(-1)

  list(
    lazy = ls(as.environment(-1)), 
    eager = ls(envir = e)
  )
}

foo <- 1
test()
#> $lazy
#> [1] "doTryCatch" "expr"       "handler"    "name"       "parentenv" 
#> 
#> $eager
#> [1] "foo"  "test"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more?  Shouldn't `as.environment(-1)` get evaluated in the parent frame since it is an explicit argument to `ls`?  How does lazyness come into this?  I thought that was primarily an issue when defining closures without forcing arguments as the closure is defined.  Sorry for being dense here.

Comment: This still looks like a bug in R.  `as.environment(-1)` should be evaluated relative to the promise's environment but it seems its not.

Comment: It's definitely not a bug. I'll add some more explanation tomorrow when I'm at a computer

Comment: @BrodieG it is evaluated in the parent environment, but I think `environment(-1)` uses not just the environment, but the _context_ (which includes the calling stack) which is not captured in the promise.